# Delete orphaned records with Ecto

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have 3 models:

user.ex

```
  schema "users" do 
    ...
    many_to_many(:acts, Act, join_through: UserAct)
  end
```

act.ex

```
  schema "acts" do
    ...
    many_to_many(:users, User, join_through: UserAct)
  end
```

user_act.ex

```
  schema "users_acts" do
    belongs_to :user, User
    belongs_to :act, Act
  end
```

Each time I delete `UserAct` I want to check if there is orphaned `Act` models and delete them, in the transaction.

In SQL it looks like this

```
DELETE FROM acts WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM users_acts ua WHERE ua.act_id = acts.id
);

or 

DELETE FROM acts WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT act_id FROM users_acts);
```

My question is how to write a similar query with Ecto?

Please show all the methods you know: joins, fragments, etc...

Comment: why not use on_delete: delete_all in your migrations ?

Comment: @script on_delete will delete all the children records when the parent is deleted, for example, if act is deleted, then all the referring user_acts will be deleted. OP wants to delete act when there are no referring user_acts. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @AbhyuditJain you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use fragments.

```
Repo.delete_all(
  from a in Act,
  where: fragment("? NOT IN (SELECT act_id FROM users_acts)", a.id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using joins:

```
orphaned_query = Act
|> join(:left, [a], a in assoc(a, :users))
|> where([a, u], is_nil(u.id))

Act
|> join(:inner, [a], a in subquery(orphaned_query))
|> Repo.delete_all()
```